# textfield selected by default-iphone

Tags: iphone, textbox, uitextfield

I want that my textfield must be focused when i open the login page in iPhone.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your viewDidLoad function for that page, call setFirstResponder on your textfield, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who are still searching.
Use

```
    [textfield becomeFirstResponder]
```

Answer (score 1):

simply take an outlet for the textfeild and write a line like [textfeildstate becomesfirstResponder]; whenever the view launches..

Answer (score 1):

Just write code in viewwillAppear 
[textField becomeFirstResponder] 
 and you work is done ..